# Robot framework: How to merge two xunit xml report files?

Tags: xml, jenkins, merge, robotframework, qtestlib

1.My robot file after running generates 4 files basically.
  output.xml, xunit.xml,report.html and log.html
2. After rerun,I want to merge the rerun generated report files with the old ones and obtain a new file.
  later,Xunit xmls are used to update qtest testcases.

I am not able to merge Xunit xmls using "--merge" command

Error:

[ ERROR ] Reading XML source '../../../xunit.xml' failed: Incompatible XML element 'testsuite'.
Please help in resolving this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first merge the output xml files and then create an xunit file out of those.

To achieve this there is a tool called `rebot` that is installed alongside with Robot Framework. After you have run your Robot Framework tests and have multiple different `output.xml` files you may run the following command:

Let's assume you have output1.xml and output2.xml.

```
rebot -R --xunit mergedxunit.xml output*.xml
```

Running that command will create a new `mergedxunit.xml` file containing all the test cases run in both `output1.xml` and `output2.xml` in xunit format. Note that if you remove the `-R` flag, new output tests will replace identical tests in the combined file.

Here is the `rebot.py` code file including information about all the different accepted parameters:
https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/blob/master/src/robot/rebot.py